# Change text input background color on selected exit

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

What property needs to be changed to change the input field color on selected text exit? I want to remove the dark grey box highlighting

(See image below)

[image]

```
<div id="ember1102" class="ember-view">

   <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg editable-row-input-right" style="display:inline-block;  " data-ember-action="1103"></i>
   <input id="alternate-name-1-265140" type="text" class="pure-input-1 pure-input-inline editable-row-input-left ember-view ember-text-field" disabled="">

</div>
```

The css is to massive to post all of it here but here is the highest level:

```
.pure-input-1.pure-input-inline.editable-row-input-left {
display:inline-block;
    min-width: 0px;

    cursor: text;

    &:disabled{
        color:inherit;
        background-color: inherit;
        padding-right: 20px;
        &:hover{
            background: inherit !important;
        }
        &:focus{

        }
    }
    &:enabled{
        color:inherit;
        background-color: white;
        &:focus{
            background: white !important;
            border: 2px solid $ecm-dark-blue !important;

        }
        &:hover{
            background: white !important;
        }
    }

}
```

changed all of the color attributes in the chrome editor I can see with no luck changing the back color.

I've also tried background and -webkit highlight

Comment: What does & stand for in your CSS?

Comment: Sorry its sass. I need to change the tags

Comment: @ShadiShaaban - use sass or less. It will change how you write CSS for good.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a combination of states which cause the darker grey background (or lighter on hover). View the consoles inspector to see what classes may be added/removed on hover/blur. You can also (in Chrome) right click the element in the inspector and manually apply states such as :hover and :focus. Perhaps this can help narrow down which css rule/class is at work here. Whatever css is active while you are :focus:hover needs to remain if :hover is falsy. Maybe an !important; clause or something if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you this worked! This tracked it down to a focus property. I added to fix this:

 `&:focus{
   background: inherit !important;
  }`